# What is the difference between modifying .htaccess file manually and installing a cache wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, caching, pagespeed

I've tested many of these caching plugins out on various Wordpress blogs but I'm still trying to figure out what the difference between using a plugin and going directly into .htaccess file and doing it manually via mod_headers. I assume the plugins do the writing to the .htaccess file for you. Why is it then that I can achieve a better page speed score if editing the .htaccess file for caching? Installing and configuring a cache plugin seems to have minimal affect on google page speed scores.

I've googled around a lot but still cannot find a decent answer to this question.

Comment: generally you measure caching in terms of server time...basically what a lot of them do is actually store a static file and obviously set the cache headers for resources. It shouldn't make more or less of a difference than setting the same htaccess rules yourself but i prefer not to use caching plugins unless it is a single server project. There is another kind of plugin, check out wordpress object caching on github, you should be able to find a couple of examples of memcache and memcached

Comment: I found this link https://github.com/ericmann/Redis-Object-Cache but I think its a bit beyond my understanding right now. I asked the question because I think I prefer setting it on the .htaccess file myself as well. How would you then "flush" the case before it is set to expire? I suppose this is one advantage of using a cache plugin.

Comment: there is no need to flush, basically this is server caching and htaccess has no effect, and data is stored on disk as opposed to db which saves time and resources. Wordpress actually has lots of server caching within its code, but without memcached or similiar its non-persistant across page loads. when you install memcached (etc) and update the wp-cache file, it now persists, so posts are cached. Wp will update the cached value if the post is modified, but you can of course update or delete cache key yourself.

Comment: Judging by the comments on this website it would still be safe to use Super Cache plugin and also write to the .htaccess file as well? I'm just not finding much concrete information about this. The case could be that server restrictions are preventing the Super Cache plugin from properly writing to the .htaccess file.

Comment: Think I found my answer here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/google-pagespeed-insights-suggests-leverage-browser-caching - different plugin but I imagine Super Cache does a similar function.